# how to make login and sign up float to right

Tags: css, inline

I want to keep my login and sign up to the right of my webpage. I've tried using `float` unsuccessfully: how do I implement this?

Here is the html page:

```html
<link href="navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<nav style="position:relative; top:1.5em;">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#.php">Home</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=".php">form</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href=".php">Profile</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="">
        <li>
            <a href="login.php">login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="new.php">Sign up</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want to use inline css to float or put my login and sign up to the right without changing my nav alignment.

Comment: Can you please provide a working example using Embeded StackOverflow Snippet or at best JSFiddle (or put your code online elsewhere) so we could test it? It's really hard to tell what's going wrong without being able to see your css code.

Comment: Couple of notes; please include your CSS, you don't have to create a `<ul>` for each navigation item. If you want some items on the left and some items on the right, create two `<ul>`, one for the left and one for the right, with the proper navigation items in them.

Comment: Obligatory "but it does work" comment: Can you define "it doesn't work"? No problem in [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/wc7yqr2u/).

Answer (score 0):

First off, it is not neccessary to create a `<ul>` for each navigation item. Instead use logical groupings of the nav items. If *a*, *b* and *c* belong together then use a single `<ul>` for all those items.

I believe you are attempting to do something like this:

```html
<nav class="cf">
    <ul class="left">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
// http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yddn822v/1/

Comment: I don't understand what you need the styles to .cf for. Can you explain? I mean, why are you injecting two tables?

Comment: Technically I don't need the clearfix as there's no background color on the `<nav>` item. In my first jsFiddle iteration I had applied a background color to the `<nav>` element. To prevent the `<nav>` element from collapsing due to the floated child elements added the [micro clearfix](// http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) class `.cf`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul style="float:right">
<li><a href="login.php">login</a></li>
</ul>
<ul style="float:right">
<li><a href="newuser.php">Sign up</a></li>
</ul>
```

this worked for me thnx for help

Comment: Though they may be illustrative I would not use inline CSS and I would remove the redundant `<ul>` markup.

Comment: Also, you said "i tried float it doesnt work" in the question. So how come it does work all of a sudden in this answer?